# PostgreSQL - Update one column with values from other columns of the same table

Tags: postgresql, if-statement, updates

I am trying to write a function that will update a column with values that are stored in one of several columns of the same table. The feeding columns represent a taxonomic hierarchy that usually is not complete so I want the receiving column to store the least high of the available values. This Is the closest I got and I sense that I am still far away :).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_taxon()
RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF taxon.subespecie is not null THEN
      UPDATE taxon SET taxon = subespecie FROM taxon;
    ELSIF taxon.especie is not null THEN
      UPDATE taxon SET taxon = especie;
    ELSIF taxon.genero is not null THEN
      UPDATE taxon SET taxon = genero;
    ELSIF taxon.subfamilia is not null THEN
      UPDATE taxon SET taxon = subfamilia;
    ELSIF taxon.familia is not null THEN
      UPDATE taxon SET taxon = familia;
    ELSIF taxon.infraordem is not null THEN
      UPDATE taxon SET taxon = infraordem;
    ELSIF taxon.subordem is not null THEN
      UPDATE taxon SET taxon = subordem;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
```

when I call the function I get this error:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "taxon" LINE 1: SELECT
>   taxon.subespecie is not null

Appart from this I also have a general doubt: what kind of `RETURN` should be declared for a function like this, that updates existing fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem you should use the built-in [`coalesce()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) function:

```
UPDATE taxon SET taxon = coalesce(subespecie, especie, genero, subfamilia, familia,
                                  infraordem, subordem)
WHERE taxon IS NULL;
```

The `coalesce()` function takes an arbitrary number of arguments and then returns the first non-null value.

Comment: Thanks Patrick - this is exactly what I need! I can now wrap it as trigger a function.